# register_setting() for single site vs update_site_option() for mu

Tags: multisite, settings-api

I'm looking at some code for an admin setting pages that goes something like this:

```
    //Save options for multisite
    if ( defined( 'MY_IS_NETWORK' ) && MY_IS_NETWORK && isset( $_POST['host'] ) ) {
        $host = esc_url_raw( $_POST['host'] );
        update_site_option( 'host', $host );
    } else {
        register_setting( 'my_settings', 'host', 'esc_url_raw' );
    }
```

Why did the developer use different functions depending on whether it was multisite or not?

Comment: this is not really a code review site. He wrote it because it felt better doing it that way. In general the answer probably boils down to network admin not having anything equivalent to the settings API, but this snippet could have been written in more elegant way

Answer (score 0):

For the **if** True section.

This code is saving into the network-wide "host" option the value of the posted host-url argument from the settings page.

For the **else** section of code.

the register_setting() is registering for the option-group 'my_settings' on the settings page it would need to have add_settings_section() and add_settings_field() to become part of the rendered settings page.  So it doesn't make sense since the settings is most likely to already be on the page.